# Does Solana Playground only work with devnet?

Tags: solana-program

[image]

Does [Solana Playground](https://beta.solpg.io/) only work with devnet?
If Solana Playground also works with mainnet, then how to switch rpc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click the gear icon and then select mainnet-beta as the endpoint

[image]